# In Espresso how can I test if *any* child of RecyclerView contains correct text

Tags: android, android-espresso, hamcrest

I have a recycler view which should contain 3 items in an unknown order.

I know how to get a recycled item by position and how to check for text

onView(withId(...)).check(matches(atPosition(0, hasDescendant(withText(A)))));

But I don't know how I can say: ***if any item*** `hasDescendant(withText(A))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create a custom `Matcher<View>`:

```
public static Matcher<View> hasItem(Matcher<View> matcher) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class) {

        @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("has item: ");
            matcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override protected boolean matchesSafely(RecyclerView view) {
            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
            for (int position = 0; position < adapter.getItemCount(); position++) {
                int type = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, type);
                adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
                if (matcher.matches(holder.itemView)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can do:

```
onView(withId(...)).check(matches(hasItem(hasDescendant(withText(...)))))
```

Or if you do not want a custom matcher, you can also use [RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions#scrollto):

```
onView(withId(...)).perform(scrollTo(hasDescendant(withText(...))))
```